Make sidenotes raggedleft in tufte-book
I am writing a document using tufte-books.
I have made the main block of text justified using the command:
\documentclass[a4paper,nofonts, twoside,justified]{tufte-book}

Additionally, I have made each chapter ragged right using the following command:
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  {\huge\rmfamily\color{red}\raggedright}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{red}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\itshape\huge\color{white}\thechapter}}}}% label
  {2pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body

How can I make the side notes left ragged instead of justified?
Please see attached file - the side note is justified.


Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your query to show the code that generates the sidenote.
